# Why can't banking apps be backed up and restored?

Tags: applications, security, backup, restore

Last night, I messed with the system and lost everything.
Had to wipe the phone and do the whole ceremony that comes after.

But the worst part was not restoring every single app, or restoring the trillions of permissions the system denies: The worst part is the **banking apps**. These apps lose permission that Titanium doesn't recover, and **I have to go to the bank to recover it. Personally.**

I live far from the city, and it happened to two banks.

Tired of this.
By far, not the first time.

I suppose the banking app uses a unique identification that the phone provides.
It's not the fingerprint (already tried Props), it's not the MAC address, and it's not the email.

So: how does the banking app identify the phone, and how do I spoof this identification? How do I keep it the same across wipes?

Comment: Probably [using keystore, which cannot be backed up](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34765340/2821954).

Comment: Thank you, Andrew. Robert (below) seems to agree.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The banking apps don't identify your device. Instead, they use cryptographic keys:

When registering your device, the app generates an asymmetric key pair (RSA or Elliptic Curves). Alternatively the bank uses a symmetric (AES) key, that is "generated" by a key agreement protocol between bank and the app. The key (pair) is generated and stored inside the `AndroidKeyStore`, a special security service that uses security hardware which allows to generate and store cryptographic keys. The public is sent to the bank or used to encrypt stored data of the app on the Android device.

These keys never leave the security element (ARM TrustZone, Google Titan, or Samsung Knox), they can only be used by the app that has generated it (stock device) but not extracted, so a backup is impossible. With root permissions, you can also talk to this security service so that every app with root permissions can make use of the stored keys, again extraction or backup is not possible.

Therefore, if an app makes use of this key store, you can't do what you want, the data and the app is bound to the device no matter what you do or what permissions you have (e.g. root).

Only in case the banking app uses the key to decrypt locally stored data, there would be a theoretical possibility to hack the app, use the key to decrypt the locally stored data, and then transfer the data to a new device, generate there a new key pair and re-encrypt the transferred data. But that requires individuals to hack each banking app which would take even a skilled hacker a few hours up to a few dozen hours.